# Count the number of occurrences of an IP in the JSON log file

Tags: python, json, list, count

I have the following data in JSON format. I want to find the number of occurrences (count) of each unique value of the `"remoteIp"` key.

```json
{
"insertId": "kdkddkdmdkd",
"jsonPayload": {
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry",
  "enforcedSecurityPolicy": {
    "configuredAction": "DENY",
    "outcome": "DENY",
    "preconfiguredExprIds": [
      "owasp-crs-v030001-id942220-sqli"
    ],
    "name": "shbdbbddjdjdjd",
    "priority": 2000
  },
  "statusDetails": "body_denied_by_security_policy"
},
"httpRequest": {
  "requestMethod": "POST",
  "requestUrl": "https://dknnkkdkddkd/token",
  "requestSize": "3004",
  "status": 403,
  "responseSize": "274",
  "userAgent": "okhttp/3.12.2",
  "remoteIp": "182.2.169.59",
  "serverIp": "10.114.44.4",
  "latency": "0.018728s"
}
```

The solution I have created till now is able to fetch all the unique `"remoteIp"`s and saved them to a set. But somehow I am not able to count the occurrence of each unique Ip in the log file.

```
import json

unique_ip = set()
request_url = set()
request_method = set()
status_code = set()
userAgent = set()

with open("automation.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

for d2 in data:
    s1 = (d2['httpRequest']['requestUrl'])
    request_url.add(''.join(s1))
    s2 = (d2['httpRequest']['requestMethod'])
    request_method.add(''.join(s2))
    s3 = (d2['httpRequest']['remoteIp'])
    unique_ip.add(''.join(s3))
    s4 = (str(d2['httpRequest']['status']))
    status_code.add(''.join(s4))
    s5 = (d2['httpRequest']['userAgent'])
    userAgent.add(''.join(s5))

def printing():
    a = str(len(unique_ip))
    b = str(len(request_url))
    c = str(len(request_method))
    d = str(len(userAgent))
    e = str(len(status_code))
    with open("output.csv", "w") as f1:
        print(
            f' {a} Unique IP List = {unique_ip}  \n {b} Unique URLs = {request_url} \n {c} Unique Req Method = {request_method} \n'
            f' {d} Unique userAgent = {userAgent} \n {e} Unique statusCode = {status_code}', file=f1)

printing()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a frequency table instead of a set. You'll go through the same amount of steps, but instead of not adding already existing IPs and other, you add to their frequency.

EDIT: added function for try catching attempts to get and save values from a response. updated example json to include a response with no status code

```py
import json
unique_ip = {}
request_url = {}
request_method = {}
status_code = {}
userAgent = {}

def getAndSaveValueSafely(freqTable, searchDict, key):
    try:
        tmp = searchDict['httpRequest'][key]
        if tmp in freqTable:
            freqTable[tmp] += 1
        else:
            freqTable[tmp] = 1
    except KeyError:
        if 'not_present' in freqTable:
            freqTable['not_present'] += 1
        else:
            freqTable['not_present'] = 1

with open("tmp.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

for d2 in data:
    getAndSaveValueSafely(request_url, d2, 'requestUrl')
    getAndSaveValueSafely(request_method, d2, 'requestMethod')
    getAndSaveValueSafely(unique_ip, d2, 'remoteIp')
    getAndSaveValueSafely(status_code, d2, 'status')
    getAndSaveValueSafely(userAgent, d2, 'userAgent')
    
    

print('request_url: ', request_url)
print('request_method: ', request_method)
print('unique_ip: ', unique_ip)
print('status_code: ', status_code)
print('userAgent: ', userAgent)
```

example list of dicts. copied your example 3 times and added another unique

```json
[
    {
    "insertId": "kdkddkdmdkd",
    "jsonPayload": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry",
      "enforcedSecurityPolicy": {
        "configuredAction": "DENY",
        "outcome": "DENY",
        "preconfiguredExprIds": [
          "owasp-crs-v030001-id942220-sqli"
        ],
        "name": "shbdbbddjdjdjd",
        "priority": 2000
      },
      "statusDetails": "body_denied_by_security_policy"
    },
    "httpRequest": {
      "requestMethod": "POST",
      "requestUrl": "https://dknnkkdkddkd/token",
      "requestSize": "3004",
      "status": 403,
      "responseSize": "274",
      "userAgent": "okhttp/3.12.2",
      "remoteIp": "182.2.169.59",
      "serverIp": "10.114.44.4",
      "latency": "0.018728s"
    }
    },
    
    {
        "insertId": "kdkddkdmdkd",
        "jsonPayload": {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry",
          "enforcedSecurityPolicy": {
            "configuredAction": "DENY",
            "outcome": "DENY",
            "preconfiguredExprIds": [
              "owasp-crs-v030001-id942220-sqli"
            ],
            "name": "shbdbbddjdjdjd",
            "priority": 2000
          },
          "statusDetails": "body_denied_by_security_policy"
        },
        "httpRequest": {
          "requestMethod": "POST",
          "requestUrl": "https://dknnkkdkddkd/token",
          "requestSize": "3004",
          "status": 403,
          "responseSize": "274",
          "userAgent": "okhttp/3.12.2",
          "remoteIp": "182.2.169.59",
          "serverIp": "10.114.44.4",
          "latency": "0.018728s"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertId": "kdkddkdmdkd",
        "jsonPayload": {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry",
          "enforcedSecurityPolicy": {
            "configuredAction": "DENY",
            "outcome": "DENY",
            "preconfiguredExprIds": [
              "owasp-crs-v030001-id942220-sqli"
            ],
            "name": "shbdbbddjdjdjd",
            "priority": 2000
          },
          "statusDetails": "body_denied_by_security_policy"
        },
        "httpRequest": {
          "requestMethod": "POST",
          "requestUrl": "https://dknnkkdkddkd/token",
          "requestSize": "3004",
          "status": 403,
          "responseSize": "274",
          "userAgent": "okhttp/3.12.2",
          "remoteIp": "182.2.169.59",
          "serverIp": "10.114.44.4",
          "latency": "0.018728s"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertId": "kdkddkdmdkd",
        "jsonPayload": {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry",
          "enforcedSecurityPolicy": {
            "configuredAction": "DENY",
            "outcome": "DENY",
            "preconfiguredExprIds": [
              "owasp-crs-v030001-id942220-sqli"
            ],
            "name": "shbdbbddjdjdjd",
            "priority": 2000
          },
          "statusDetails": "body_denied_by_security_policy"
        },
        "httpRequest": {
          "requestMethod": "GET",
          "requestUrl": "https://temp/token",
          "requestSize": "3004",
          "status": 403,
          "responseSize": "274",
          "userAgent": "okhttp/3.11.2",
          "remoteIp": "182.2.168.59",
          "serverIp": "10.113.44.4",
          "latency": "0.018728s"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertId": "kdkddkdmdkd",
        "jsonPayload": {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry",
          "enforcedSecurityPolicy": {
            "configuredAction": "DENY",
            "outcome": "DENY",
            "preconfiguredExprIds": [
              "owasp-crs-v030001-id942220-sqli"
            ],
            "name": "shbdbbddjdjdjd",
            "priority": 2000
          },
          "statusDetails": "body_denied_by_security_policy"
        },
        "httpRequest": {
          "requestMethod": "GET",
          "requestUrl": "https://temp/token",
          "requestSize": "3004",
          "responseSize": "274",
          "userAgent": "okhttp/3.11.2",
          "remoteIp": "182.2.168.59",
          "serverIp": "10.113.44.4",
          "latency": "0.018728s"
        }
    }
]
```

output from running code

```
request_url:  {'https://dknnkkdkddkd/token': 3, 'https://temp/token': 2}
request_method:  {'POST': 3, 'GET': 2}
unique_ip:  {'182.2.169.59': 3, '182.2.168.59': 2}
status_code:  {403: 4, 'not_present': 1}
userAgent:  {'okhttp/3.12.2': 3, 'okhttp/3.11.2': 2}
```

Comment: Just one more doubt, the 'status' key is present inside in some 'httpRequest' but in the same log file under 'httpRequest', the 'status' key is not present. It is throwing error like below: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxxx/Downloads/xxxx/example.py", line 30, in <module>
    s4 = (str(d2['httpRequest']['status']))
KeyError: 'status' 
can you suggest any solution that can be used to tackle this?

Comment: add a try catch for each element you're looking for. if you want to record that a certain response didn't have that element, you can include a "not_present" key in that freqTable and add to it in the catch for the try

Comment: I tried using try catch and it works fine for 4 keys but for the 'useragent' key it is throwing an error. `    try:
        s5 = (d2['httpRequest']['userAgent'])
        if s5 in userAgent:
            userAgent[s5] += 1
        else:
            userAgent[s5] = 1
    except ErrorUserAgent:
        ErrorUserAgent.update([s5])

Pasting the error in next comment.

Comment: error: Traceback (most recent call last):
    s5 = (d2['httpRequest']['userAgent'])
KeyError: 'userAgent'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    except ErrorUserAgent:
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

Comment: @ManikSharma editted my answer to include the try except, made the logic of that try catch it's own method

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest thing to do is use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of a `set` to track the `removeIp`s encountered. It's a dictionary subclass and like a dictionary, the keys must all be unique, plus it keeps track of how many times each key is "added".

Here is the modified code:

```
from collections import Counter
import json

request_url = set()
request_method = set()
unique_ip = Counter()
status_code = set()
userAgent = set()

with open("automation.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

for d2 in data:
    s1 = d2['httpRequest']['requestUrl']
    request_url.add(''.join(s1))
    s2 = d2['httpRequest']['requestMethod']
    request_method.add(''.join(s2))
    s3 = d2['httpRequest']['remoteIp']
    unique_ip.update([s3])
    s4 = str(d2['httpRequest']['status'])
    status_code.add(''.join(s4))
    s5 = d2['httpRequest']['userAgent']
    userAgent.add(''.join(s5))

def printing():
    a = len(unique_ip)
    b = len(request_url)
    c = len(request_method)
    d = len(userAgent)
    e = len(status_code)
    with open("output.csv", "w") as f1:
        print(
            f' {a} Unique IP List = {unique_ip}  \n {b} Unique URLs = {request_url} \n {c} Unique Req Method = {request_method} \n'
            f' {d} Unique userAgent = {userAgent} \n {e} Unique statusCode = {status_code}', file=f1)

printing()
```

Note that the file you are creating is **not** in CSV format, so isn't one.

With that said, if I copied your example data 3 times and added another with a different `remoteIp`, this is what is written to the `"output.csv"` file:

```
 2 Unique IP List = Counter({'182.2.169.59': 3, '182.2.168.59': 1})  
 1 Unique URLs = {'https://dknnkkdkddkd/token'} 
 1 Unique Req Method = {'POST'} 
 1 Unique userAgent = {'okhttp/3.12.2'} 
 1 Unique statusCode = {'403'}
```

Note what is written at the beginning for the "Unique IP List".